# Автомасштабирование по высоте блоков слева и справа

Tags: html, вёрстка, css, height

Есть верстка. Фиксированный родительский слой имеет высоту `height:768px`;  А составные части имеют высоту в %. Хочу добиться грамотного авто-масштабирования по высоте блоков слева и справа от планеты (а по хорошему и шапку и подвал) от высоты монитора (браузера) пользователя и его разрешения. Невозможно?

[image]

Comment: Спасибо большое за грамотную модификацию вопроса!

Answer (score 1):

Например, у родителя указать `min-height:768px; height:auto;`

Comment: Не очень помогло. Но все равно спасибо.